# Что означает вопрос в стихотворении М. В. Ломоносова?

Tags: литература, история

Наткнулся на стихотворение М. В. Ломоносова "О сомнительном произношении буквы г в российском языке". Что означает выделенный мной вопрос в конце стихотворения?

> Бугристы берега, благоприятны влаги,
> О горы с гроздами, где греет юг ягнят,
> О грады, где торги, где мозгокружны браги,
> И деньги, и гостей, и годы их губят.
> Драгие ангелы, пригожие богини,
> Бегущие всегда от гадкия гордыни,
> Пугливы голуби из мягкого гнезда,
> Угодность с негою, огромные чертоги, 
> Недуги наглые и гнусные остроги,
> Богатство, нагота, слуги и господа. 
> Угрюмы взглядами, игрени, пеги, смуглы, 
> Багровые глаза, продолговаты, круглы, 
> И кто горазд гадать и лгать, да не мигать,
> Играть, гулять, рыгать и ногти огрызать, 
> Ногаи, болгары, гуроны, геты , гунны, 
> Тугие головы, о йготи чугунны, 
> Гневливые враги и гладкословный друг,
> Толпыги, щеголи, когда вам есть досуг. 
> От вас совета жду, я вам даю на волю:
> **Скажите, где быть га и где стоять глаголю?**

Comment: Вам, позиционирующему себя историком, должно быть известно, кем был Ломоносов - и по какому поводу он написал это стихотворение.  
Речь шла об исторических изменениях в фонетике русского языка - и полемике по этому поводу возникшей.
Искать смысл в ироническом вопросе памфлетного стихотфорения - не есть гуд...

Comment: На исторических факультетах поэзию и фонетику не изучают.

Comment: А вот пререкаться с Вами я не буду.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это Ломоносов, ратующий за правильность языка и против его усложнения, так прекратил спор о необходимости введения новой буквы,показав нелепость затеи:    http://www.proza.ru/2010/12/19/1389